# Как можно свертать такой блок?

Tags: html, css

Как можно свертать такой блок? То есть стрелочка снизу между двумя блоками, при этом адаптивность.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно вы имеете в виду под словом "адаптивность", какая конкретно адаптивность вам нужна?

Comment: Банально чтобы при уменьшении ширины экрана, стрелочка не сдвигалась.

Comment: Найдите картинку с такой стрелкой, поставьте её на after или before. Как вариант

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью background-image стрелку ставят в качестве фона.
С помощью background-size указывают размер картинки.
С помощью background-position указывают положение картинки внутри родителя.

Если адаптив то можно менять размер и положение картинки c помощью медиа запросов. Если нужно картинку тоже можно поменять.

```
/* Для смартфонов */
@media screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  element {
    background-image: "./images/3.png";
    background-position: 30px 10px;
    background-size: 200px 20px;
  }
}
/* Для пк */
@media screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  element {
    background-image: "./images/3.png";
    background-position: 70px 30px;
    background-size: 300px 30px;
  }
}
```